# the chart in angular is not re-rendering when i change the input data

Tags: angular, chart.js

parent component : appComponent

child component: chartComponent

I have a shared/common chart component and i have a dropdown , based on dropdown selection i am making a service call and getting the data and passing that data to child(chartComponent) component.

problem is when i select the dropdown and click on apply button first time it is working fine but second time if change the dropdown and click on apply, chart is not re-rendering

here is the code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-starter-project-daidh-lh8thg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fchart%2Fchart.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, the issue is that the child component is not being notified about the changes in the dropdown selection. To fix it, you can add `ngOnChanges()` method to the child component to update the chart whenever the `label` is changed:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['labels'] && this.chart) {
        this.chart.data.datasets = this.dataSets;
        this.chart.data.labels = this.labels;
        this.chart.update();
    }
}
```